# T(n) = T(n/10) + T(an) + n, how to solve this?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, space-complexity

**Update: I'm still looking for a solution without using something from outside sources.**

**Given:** `T(n) = T(n/10) + T(an) + n` for some `a`, and that: `T(n) = 1` if `n < 10`, I want to check if the following is possible (for some `a` values, and I want to find the *smallest possible* `a`):

> For every *`c > 0`* there is *`n0 > 0`* such that for every *`n > n0`*, *`T(n) >= c * n`*

I tried to open the function declaration step by step but it got really complicated and I got stuck since I see no advancement at all.

Here is what I did: (Sorry for adding an image, that's because I wrote a lot on word and I cant paste it as text)

Any help please?

[image]

Comment: You should clear is `a < 1`?

Comment: @OmG I should find the smallest a which makes the above statement true

Answer (score 2):

Invoking [Akra–Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), g(n) = n¹, so the critical exponent is p = 1, so we want (1/10)¹ + a¹ = 1, hence a  = 9/10.

Intuitively, this is like the mergesort recurrence: with linear overhead at each call, if we don't reduce the total size of the subproblems, we'll end up with an extra log in the running time (which will overtake any constant c).

Comment: the mergesort reference applies for a==0.9. you've probably intended it that way, but perhaps it's better said explicitly. also it seems clear that T(n)=O(n) for a<0.9 and T(n)=INF for a=1.0. but what about 0.9 < a < 1.0? (or am I completely wrong here?)

Comment: @WillNess 0.9 < a < 1 is supercritical, so you wind up with a running time on the order of n^c for some c > 1.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat the problem is that I am not allowed to use this method as a proof since I didn't learn it

Comment: @WhiteForce use the substitution method to prove that when T(n) = T(n/10) + T(9n/10) + n, you have T(n) ≥ (1/1000) (n log n - n). Then use it again to prove that when T(n) = T(n/10) + T(an) + n for some a < 9/10, we have T(n) ≤ (1000/(9/10 - a)) n.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721244/calculate-complexity-of-tn?

Answer (score 0):

Another perspective: draw a recursion tree and count the work done per level. The work done in each layer of the tree will be (1/10 + a) as much as the work of the level above it. (Do you see why?)

If (1/10 + a) < 1, this means the work per level is decaying geometrically, so the total work done will sum to some constant multiple of n (whose leading coefficient depends on a). If (1 / 10 + a) ≥ 1, then the work done per level stays the same or grows from one level to the next, so the total work done now depends (at least) on the number of layers in the tree, which is Θ(log n) because the subproblems sizes are dropping by a constant from one layer to the next and that can’t happen more than Θ(log n) times. So once (1 / 10 + a) = 1 your runtime suddenly is Ω(n log n) = ω(n).

(This is basically the reasoning behind the Master Theorem, just applied to non-uniform subproblems sizes, which is where the Akra-Bazzi theorem comes from.)

Comment: "The work done in each layer of the tree will be (1/10 + a) as much as the work of the level above it" But T(n) isn't the same as n... plus the work at first level is T(n) why the second level is T(n/10)+T(an) + n so what you stated doesn't apply...

Comment: I agree that T(n) isn’t the same as n. Look at the first recursive call. It does n work, then fires off a call of size n/10 and a call of size an. The call of size n/10 does n/10 work, and the call of size an does an work, for a total of (1/10 + a)n work, plus some further recursive calls. That’s why the work drops to a (1/10 + a) factor. I encourage you to actually draw out the recursion tree - it’s a powerful visual!

Comment: I just draw the true but have some problems, like why u said the number of layers is $log_n(n)$? it is the max between $log_n(n)$ and $log_{1/10}(n)$ plus some layers are not full... I'm so confused

Comment: @WhiteForce If I said that the number of layers was log_n (n), this was an error on my part (note that log_n(n)). However, the number of layers in the tree is indeed logarithmic. If a <= 1/10, then the depth of the tree is at most log_10 n; if 1/10 < a < 1, then the tree will have log_{1/a} n layers. Either way, that's Theta(log n) layers assuming n is a constant. (Continued...)

Comment: @WhiteForce And you are correct that not all layers in the tree will be full, but a logarithmic number of them are guaranteed to be full. If a <= 1/10, then the first log_(1/a) n layers will be full; if 1/10 < a < 1, then the first log_10 a layers will be full. Either way, that's Theta(log n) full layers.

Comment: Ok I got here and want to continue formal solution what should I do next? plus why you got a should be exactly 9/10 there are multiple values but 9/10 is the smallest one... https://i.imgur.com/guLVPi9.png

Comment: I'm going to leave it to you to figure out the remaining steps. We've discussed the major insights and ideas here: working one layer at a time, looking for a phase transition, etc. Keep playing around with this - I'm sure you'll figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement:**

> For every c > 0 there is n0 > 0 such that for every n > n0, T(n) >= c*n

By substituting the recurrence in the inequality and solving for a, you will get:

```
T(n) >= c*n

(c*n/10) + (c*a*n) + n >= c*n 

a >= 0.9 - (1/c)
```

Since our desired outcome is for all c (treat c as infinity), we get a >= 0.9. Therefore, smallest value of `a` is 0.9 which will satisfy `T(n) >= c*n` for all c.

Comment: @WhiteForce Did you get a chance to look at my solution? I assume `T(n) >= c * n` to hold for any c and solve for the inequality. I apply limit c tends to infinity as that will maximize the value of RHS and also as our goal is to hold the inequality for any c.