# Calculate Complexity of T(n)?

Tags: function, recursion, tree, time-complexity, big-o

**Given:** `T(n) = T(n/10) + T(an) + n` for some `a` (which I know nothing about its value), and that: `T(n) = 1` if `n < 10`.

I want to check if the following is possible (for some `a` values, and I want to find the *smallest possible* `a`):

> For every *`c > 0`* there is *`n0 > 0`* such that for every *`n > n0`*, *`T(n) >= c * n`* Or in other words T(n)=omega(n)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hello, can you accept my answer, please and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that a < 9/10. Let c = max(1/(9/10 - a), 1), so that c ≥ 1 and 1/c ≤ 9/10 - a. Then for 1 ≤ n < 10,

```
T(n) = 1 ≤ n ≤ cn.
```

Inductively, for n ≥ 10,

```
T(n)
= T(n/10) + T(an) + n
≤ cn/10 + can + n
= c(1/10 + a + 1/c)n
≤ c(1/10 + a + 9/10 - a)n
= cn.
```

Now suppose that a = 9/10. For 1 ≤ n < 10, we know log10 n < 1 and therefore

```
T(n) = 1 > n log10 n - n.
```

Inductively, for n ≥ 10,

```
T(n)
= T(n/10) + T(9n/10) + n
> (n/10) log10 (n/10) - (n/10) + (9n/10) log10 (9n/10) - (9n/10) + n
= (n/10) log10 (n/10) + (9n/10) log10 (9n/10)
> (n/10) log10 (n/10) + (9n/10) log10 ( n/10)
= (n/10) (log10 n - 1) + (9n/10) (log10 n - 1)
= n log10 n - n.
```

Given c > 0, pick n0 such that log10 n0 - 1 = c, i.e., n0 = exp10(c + 1). Then for all n > n0,

```
T(n) > n log10 n - n = n(log10 n - 1) > n(log10 n0 - 1) = cn.
```

Answer (score 1):

> For every c > 0 there is n0 > 0 such that for every n > n0, T(n) >= c*n

We assume T(n) >= cn holds for some a and every c > 0.

By substituting the recurrence in the inequality and solving for a, you will get:

```
T(n) >= c*n

(c*n/10) + (c*a*n) + n >= c*n 

a >= (9/10) - (1/c)
```

Since our desired outcome is to hold for all c (formally apply limit c tends to infinity, which is where RHS will maximize), we get a >= (9/10). Therefore, smallest value of `a` is (9/10) which will satisfy `T(n) >= c*n` for all c.

After this, you can prove by induction, that this is indeed the case.

Answer (score 0):

In each function, you need to find the highest impacting variable of the equation. On the big scale, the smallest possible N affecting this function is any Constant.